# sagemaker training job doesn't create tar file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I have trained some models whose artifqcts I can see in my S3 bucket, including the safe tensors, and other resources. But It has not created any tar file for inference. Or if I wanted to transfer the model to other architectures, I can't seem to do that. I can't even download this folder as such. Does anyone know how I can create the tar file?

I tried to create the model from the training job, but it also points to the same location, without the tar file

Comment: What compression type are you setting when starting the training job? If it is set to `NONE` then [uncompressed model upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-train-storage.html#model-train-storage-uncompressed) will be enabled and no tar file will be produced.

Comment: @PaytonStaub I just checked this. i was using the default training functions where compression was disabled. Thanks